# Summarizing fixed effects variables in Stata

Tags: stata, fixed-effects-model

Using a data set of 209 countries, I have run a fixed effects regression for non-[OECD](http://www.oecd.org/) countries.

When I summarize my variables, it gives me all of the variables in data set, but I only need a summary of those variables that have been used in my fixed effects regression.  For instance, when I run fixed effects, the number of groups is 138. So, my total observations for a variable should be 138 multiplied by 26 years (1980-2006), which is only 3588 observations.

How can I ask Stata to generate this?

Answer (score 3):

Stata leaves the quasi-variable `e(sample)` after any estimation command. You can use it as `summarize x1 x2 x3 if e(sample)`.

In general, you should develop a habit of looking into the guts of Stata with `ereturn list` after estimation. You may be able to find a lot of useful additional information.

Answer (score 0):

`-estat summarize-` will give summaries of the sample used in the most recent estimation command. See `-help postestimation-`, or the `postestimation` help for the specific command you are using.

Comment: I agree with @timbp. But if you require summaries for variables not in the regression then stata can mark your sample by creating a dummy variable. Just type"mark sample" and you will get the dummy. Thus you can use the IF sample==1 along with your specific summary command.